# Which was the first anime featuring power levels?

Tags: tropes

Severals animes have the idea of power levels, in those universes a technological or magical device exists to give a figure to the combat power of an individual. Three of them I know are Dragon Ball Z, One Punch Man and Nanatsu no Taizai. But which anime was the first to feature this concept?

Comment: Dragon Ball has been around a lot longer than the other two but I would think that Dragon Ball was not the first either.

Comment: After a quick cursory research, it seems that Dragon Ball *did* invent the concept of Power Levels. Even the Dragon Ball wiki lists the power levels as being fully original. They compare ki and fighting styles to the (older) writing of Ring ni Kakero, but RnK didn't use power levels.